# Displaying API data in Joomla Component

Tags: joomla-api

So, this is a two parted question but both pertaining to REST APIs.  I am developing a component for Joomla in which I have a few database fields (ie. teamid and platform) that are stored in the local db.  These two fields correlate to a rest API from an external source.

If table #__nhlleague_team table has the three fields:

ID, teamid, platform

The API I am pulling from in general is

https://proclubs.ea.com/api/nhl/clubs/info?clubIds=*teamid*&platform=*platform*

for example

https://proclubs.ea.com/api/nhl/clubs/info?clubIds=196556&platform=xboxone

So, the question is - how do I insert the GET request in the Joomla Component?  Would it be its own function in the Model?  I just need the data to be displayed based on those parameters, and have no idea how to implement in the component.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is probably suited as a function/method of a Model as it is accessing data, some people might put it in a sub-controller, however I don't believe Controllers are supposed to deal with data.

These are the basic lines that you need to set up your request, make the call and then output the results.

```
    use Joomla\Http\Http;
.
.
.
    $url = 'https://proclubs.ea.com/api/nhl/clubs/info?clubIds=196556&platform=xboxone';
    $http = new Http();
    $reponse = $http->get($url);
    print_r($reponse);
```